# Having an issue with fancy box in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am having issues with the add on "fancy box" on my site in IE and Firefox.
http://pinnacle2.us

When previewed in Chrome everything works perfectly. I have researched the previous question from this site and alot of them suggest adding Doctypes to fix the problem, but either I am doing something wrong or the suggestions are not working.

I am new to all of this so any suggestion in simple terms would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link :

http://webdev.plentyinfo.com/2010/12/fancybox-problems-in-ie/

This is really helps to you.

Comment: Thank you for your link, but I am new to creating. Im not sure what all of this is trying to get me to do. Is it possible to better explain to a nwebie what to do?